# Does SQL Server Compact Edition (SqlCe) have a SNAPSHOT table like Oracle Lite?

Tags: sql-server-ce, snapshot

In Oracle Lite, you can create a SNAPSHOT table which is like a normal table except that it tracks changes to itself.  The syntax is

```
CREATE SNAPSHOT TABLE tblWhatever ...
```

and you can perform CRUD operations on it like a normal table.  To get the change information, you query the table like this:

```
SELECT * FROM tblWhatever + WHERE ...
```

which returns all the rows in the table (including deleted ones) meeting the WHERE clause, and you can access each row's `row_state` column as a normal field (which is invisible to a normal `SELECT * FROM tblWhatever WHERE ...` query).

Is there some way to do the same thing with Sql Compact Edition (3.5) - i.e. create a table that tracks changes without using RDA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, it looks like "yes", as long as you have SqlCe 3.5 SP2:

http://blogs.msdn.com/sqlservercompact/